# Angular 7 - not initialize interface from http.post response

Tags: json, angular, http

I have a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Order} from './interfaces/Order';
import {OrderResponse} from './interfaces/OrderResponse';
import {AuthorizeRequest} from './interfaces/AuthorizeRequest';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public addOrder(newOrder: Order){
    return this.http.post<OrderResponse>('http://localhost:8080/order/add', newOrder, httpOptions)
  }

}
```

And order component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Order} from '../interfaces/Order';
import {OrderService} from '../order.service';
import {OrderResponse} from '../interfaces/OrderResponse';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orderpage',
  templateUrl: './orderpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orderpage.component.css']
})
export class OrderpageComponent implements OnInit {
  public order: Order;
  public orderResponse: OrderResponse;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.order = {
      dateOfService: '',
      city: '',
      address: '',
      apartmentSize: 0,
      phoneNumber: '',
      status: "ORDERED",
      client: null
    };

    this.orderResponse = {
      orderId: 0,
      price: 0
    };
  }

  public addOrder(){
    this.orderService.addOrder(this.order).subscribe(response => {
        this.orderResponse = response;
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

When I send post request, backend return me OrderResponse. I can display this data in console.log(response), but I can't save to interface orderResponse. What is the problem? The orderResponse always is empty.

Comment: An `interface` is a group of related properties and methods that describe an object, but neither provides implementation nor initialization for them. So you can't save to an `interface`, It's just used to ensure that proper values/properties are passed to class that implements it.

Comment: *The orderResponse always is empty.* what does that mean, precisely? How do you test that the order response always is empty? Note that your http options are unnecessary: HttpClient sets the JSON content type automatically.

Comment: Can you please show me a sample of response you get from the back end

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing?

Comment: @user11149927: Make sure keys in interface matches keys in API response

Comment: I added post below.